# How to center 3 factors in one table?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I want to center the 3 factors in the bottom line in the under table"Ref1.i, Ref1.ii and Ref1.iii". Just as the upper line showed. I'm entry level, thank you for any kind help!

code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,multirow}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{booktabs,multirow}

\begin{document}
\centering
Table 1. Table testing\\
\begin{tabular}{*{4}{c}}
    \toprule
    \textbf{Title1} & \textbf{Title2} & \textbf{Title3} & \textbf{Title4} \\
    \midrule
    \textbf{Ref1} & Val2a & Val3a $\left\{\begin{tabular}{@{\ }l@{}}
        Ref1.i \\ Ref1.ii \\ Ref1.iii
    \end{tabular}\right.$ & Val4a \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{*{4}{c}}
    \toprule
    \textbf{Title1} & \textbf{Title2} & \textbf{Title3} & \textbf{Title4} \\
    \midrule
    \multirow{3}{*}{\textbf{Ref1}} & \multirow{3}{*}{Val2a} & Ref1.i & \multirow{3}{*}{Val4a} \\
        & & Ref1.ii & \\
        & & Ref1.iii & \\
    \multirow{3}{*}{\textbf{Ref1}} & \ Ref1.i & \multirow{3}{*}{Val3a} &\multirow{3}{*}{ } \\
        & Ref1.ii & \\
        & Ref1.iii & \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: The only thin destroying the central alignment of these elements is the explicit space `\ ` before `Ref1.i`.  Just remove that those three elements will be centered in their column.

Comment: @AndrewSwann Thank you! That is what I want.